# What pythagorean table looked like?

Tags: mathematics

Pythagoras  introduced the multiplication table in Southern Italy about 500 BC, do we know how it looked like?

**Edit**

I do not mean the so called pytagorean/multiplication/times table but the **actual table 'invented' by Pythagoras** about 500 BC

Comment: See [Multiplication Table : Hisory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_table#History) : "The multiplication table is sometimes attributed to the ancient Greek mathematician Pythagoras (570–495 BC). It is also called the Table of Pythagoras in many languages The Greco-Roman mathematician Nichomachus (60–120 AD), a follower of Neopythagoreanism, included a multiplication table in his *Introduction to Arithmetic*, whereas the oldest surviving Greek multiplication table is on a wax tablet dated to the 1st century AD and currently housed in the British Museum."

Comment: See [reproduction](https://books.google.it/books?id=56lzDQAAQBAJ&pg=PA58).

Comment: I started from there, i am asking to know what it looked like